# 9 hens lay 9 eggs in 9 days...

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics

9 hens lay 9 eggs in 9 days. How many eggs will 3 hens lay in 3 days??? it's a tricky question asked by a friend and can you solve it and explain your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, I would suggest you to explain what you did to try to solve you so other people could help you better. Good luck! And the title of the question should try to explain what is the question about.

Comment: A hen is not a well-defined mathematical object. As such, this is completely unknowable.

Comment: What is the distribution of egg-laying?  uniform?

Comment: The given 9 day problem is associated with a 9X 9 (day /hen) matrix with a total of 9 added each way, well defined.But unless you say that the new breed of hens is capable of laying a single egg in at most 3 days , we cannot conclude that the number eggs =3. Generally unsolvable for insufficient data.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Nine women produce nine babies in nine months. How many babies are produced by three women in three months?

Answer (score 2):

With one-third the number of hens and one-third the number of days, one would have one-ninth the number of eggs, thus just one.

Comment: Unless for e.g., these hens average an egg every 9 days, in which case you could have 0-9 eggs, or is it a max of 27? ;)

Comment: i didn't understand your explanation, i'm not that good in maths but the answer is 1 (my friend told me) but i want to know why the answer is 1?? Thanks

Comment: @user230172 What part of the explanation did you not understand?

Comment: If nine hens lay nine eggs in nine days, then on average each hen lays one egg every nine days.  Imagine the first hen laying an egg on the first day of the month, the second hen on the second day, and so on, until the ninth hen lays an egg on the ninth day.  If you just had the third, sixth, and ninth hens, you'd get one egg from the third hen in the first three days, one from the sixth in the next three days, and one from the ninth in the next three days, so one egg every three days.  On the other hand, if you had the first, second and third hens, you'd get.....

Comment: .....three eggs in the first three days, but none in the next six days.  Thus if you consume just one egg in the first three days and save the other two for the next six days, then you'd have one for the next three days and one for the three days after that, thus one every three days.